# Fabric JS Replace Objects with Same Item(ID)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to replace the Circle shape with Rectangle shape with same Item Number used by canvas

First I created Circle :

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
left: 200,
top: 200,
radius: 30,
fill: 'gray',
stroke: 'black',
strokeWidth: 3}));
```

Then replace with Rectangle:

```
var Rectangle = new fabric.Rect({ 
width: 100, 
height: 150,
fill: 'blue', 
stroke: 'red' });
```

Assume that Circle is canvas.item(0) i need to replace Rectangle with same Id canvas.item(0) :

Something like This :

```
canvas.item(0).replace(Rectangle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the rectangle with `canvas.remove(Circle)`

and add the new item with `canvas.insertAt(Rectangle, 0, false)`.

see: [insertAt fabricJS Docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#insertAt)